# Iterate over objects and access them as casted

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to iterate over a map and cast objects, then somehow reference them as already casted.

Assume `Test1` and `Test2` are totally different classes, but both have a method named equally `get_class_specific_field()`

```
HashMap<Class,Object> objects = new HashMap<>();
```

then inside `Test1` and `Test2` classes I do respectively:

```
objects.put(Test1.class,this);

objects.put(Test2.class,this);
```

This is a normal way of iterating:

```
for( Map.Entry<Class, Object> entry : objects.entrySet()){
    if(Object instanceof Test1){
        Test1 castedObj = (Test1)entry.getValue();
        castedObj.get_class_specific_field();
    }

    if(Object instanceof Test2){
        Test2 castedObj = (Test2)entry.getValue();
        castedObj.get_class_specific_field();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to somehow avoid if blocks, e.g.

```
for( Map.Entry<Class, Object> entry : objects.entrySet()){
    ???? castedObj = entry.getValue()).cast(entry.getKey());
    castedObj.get_class_specific_field(); 
}
```

Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: If the method has the same name and if it makes sense, `Test1` and `Test2` should implement a common interface. Then, Your map becomes a `HashMap<Class, YourCommonInterface>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using interfaces it would be possible by just casting to that interface.

If you can't do that you could use reflection and lookup the method but that might break e.g. if the method name changes etc.

Another approach would be to use some sort of handler that knows how to handle a specific class and which is selected based on that class.

Example:

```
interface Handler {
  void handle( Object o );
  Class<?> getHandledClass();
}

class Test1Handler implements Handler() {
  public void handle( Object o ) {
    ((Test1)o).callSomeSpecificMethod();
  }

  public Class<?> getHandledClass() {
    return Test1.class;
  }      
}
```

Usage:

```
Map<Class<?>, Handler> handlers = ...;
Test1Handler test1Handler = new Test1Handler();
handlers.put( test1Handler.getHandledClass(), test1Handler );
//and others

for( Map.Entry<Class, Object> entry : objects.entrySet()){
  Handler h = handlers.get( entry.getKey() ); //ofc you need to "handle" unknown types etc. ;)
  h.handle( entry.getValue() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to put the type on the left. You have several options.

1)

```
Class c = entry.getKey();
Object castedObj = entry.getValue()
castedObj.cast(c).get_class_specific_field(); // cast every time
```

Casting every time is not pretty, but also doesn't affect performance. It's only relevant for the compiler and code reader.

2) Use some interface / class hierarchy and override `get_class_specific_field`.

3) Use the Visitor Design Pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Create

```
interface SpecialFieldGetter<T>{
      T get_class_specific_field();
}
```

Implement interface in Test1 and Test2